# How to set Id when opening dialog from a bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm opening dialog from a backing bean like this:

```
Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    options.put("resizable", true);
                    options.put("width", 1400);
                    options.put("contentWidth", "100%");
                    options.put("height", 800);
                    //...

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("/some.xhtml", options, null);
```

How can I set the dialog id?

I tried to put it like an option, but it didn't help:

```
options.put("id", "someId");
```

Thank you!
p.s. Primefaces version 5.3

Comment: I don't think you can. And try 6.2 please, just for this issue to see if it is by accident (or intentionally) fixed